# trying to convert a string to a decimal for iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I have an app that this was all working correctly before iOS 13. I've checked a few posts but they seem to be saying what I have already done.

I'm passing a string that has currency symbols and formatting, and I want to strip that and use the string value.

```
func changeCurrencyToDecimal(stringNumber:String) -> Decimal {


    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

    // Pull apart the components of the user's locale
    var locComps = Locale.components(fromIdentifier: Locale.current.identifier)
    // Set the specific currency code
    locComps[NSLocale.Key.currencyCode.rawValue] = options?.currencyCode // or any other specific currency code
    // Get the updated locale identifier
    let locId = Locale.identifier(fromComponents: locComps)
    // Get the new custom locale
    //numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: locId)

    if(options?.currencyCode == nil) {
           print("There is no currency code so use the default locale")
           numberFormatter.locale = Locale.current
       }
       else{
           print("We have a currency code!")
           numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: locId)
       }

    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    numberFormatter.currencySymbol = ""
    numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = ","  

    print("\(stringNumber) is the number being passed")

    let number = numberFormatter.number(from: stringNumber)

    // check to see if the number is nil and if so, return 0.

    print("\(number) is the number converted")
    if number == nil{
        return 0
    }
    else{
        print("\(number!) is the number")
        let amount = number?.decimalValue
        return amount!
    }

}
```

An example of a string that I am passing: $300.00 the $ always triggers a return of nil. If I pass 300.00, then the converter works just fine. But I need to be able to check for any currency the user has set for their device.

The currency codes that I am checking are the ones Apple supplies in the `var currencyCode: String? { get }` options is just where I am storing those codes.

The numberFormatter produces nil every time, and it seems because my decimal is not being stripped of its formatting.

Again this worked before iOS 13, so I am guessing something changed on Apple's side and I just might not have come acrossed it yet.

**UPDATE**
Here is a user seniaro. The user enters an amount. If the user hits save right away, I take the amount and convert it into a decimal to save in coredata. But if the user dismisses the keyboard, I take that amount and convert it into a string to display the currency symbol. I allow the user to set their currency, so using the locale doesn't work for me, as sometimes they are not using that system. So after the keyboard is dismissed and their amount is displayed with the correct formatting, I have it programmed that if they would happen to change their amount and once again dismiss the keyboard, and the same steps are repeated. The currency symbols are stripped and the string is converted into a decimal.

I hope this better gives you an idea of how this works in my app.

**UPDATE**
I've added an if/else statement to see if the locale has been set or if it comes back nil, and if so to set it to the Locale.current

Comment: Is the currency string always going to be in a specific format with a specific decimal separator or is it a string a user entered in their customary format for their locale? Why are you hardcoding a decimal separator to a comma but attempting to parse a decimal string using a period? Why do you jump through hoops to set the locale?

Comment: The user is able to set the locale, so I can't predict what format the currency will be in. I'm trying to strip the currency of all formatting, and use that decimal.

Comment: If the user is entering the string in their own locale then the solution is trivial. Remove all the unnecessary code you have to setup the number formatter. Create it and set the style. That's it. Don't set any other properties of the number formatter other than the style.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input string is using the device's current locale you can create a `NumberFormatter` with `Locale.current` and set the `numberStyle` to currency.

I used a small playground to test it:

```
import Foundation

func changeCurrencyToDecimal(_ stringNumber: String) -> Decimal? {
  let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
  numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency

  let number = numberFormatter.number(from: stringNumber)
  return number?.decimalValue
}

let numbersFormatted = ["$300", "$3,000.04", "3.000,04", "Wazaa", "3000000"]
numbersFormatted
  .map { changeCurrencyToDecimal($0) }
  .forEach { print($0 ?? "Not a value") }
```

This prints:

- 300
- 3000.04
- Not a value
- Not a value
- 3000000

If you keep getting `nil` as a result your device's locale is different as the sample string number you are using in the question ($300).

Comment: 1. No need to set the locale to `Locale.current`. That's the default. 2. The output of the code in this answer depends on the locale of the user running the code.

Comment: You are right that no need to set the locale to current, I'll edit the answer. The output does depend on the device's config but I think as the function returns a `decimal` that's what @icekomo needs.

Comment: I mean for some users, the 2nd string will give "Not a value" and the 3rd string will give "3000.04". For others, both the 2nd and 3rd strings will give "Not a value". It depends on the user's grouping and decimal separators for their locale.

Comment: Sure, that's why it work for me with the second string and not the third one. I set the third string with incorrect grouping and decimal separator according to my machine's config so @icekomo could see the same number failing because of the incorrect format of the input string.

Comment: I updated this question to give you an example of a user using this part of the app.

Comment: It seems that it's failing on this line: 
let number = numberFormatter.number(from: stringNumber)

even though I am giving it a string of "$10.00" to convert to a number, it returns nil

Comment: This answer has problem with precision. For example if I use `"$0.94"` I get the result `0.9399999999999999`. What could be done to make the result exactly `0.94`?